# Is the apico-labial trill a phoneme in any language?

Tags: phonology, trills

As far as anyone here knows, are there any natural languages in which the apico-labial trill is a phoneme?

Comment: i think you are referring to an articulation where the tongue apex touches the lips and the lips vibrate against the tongue apex. i haven't thought through the aerodynamics of such an articulation, but I am struggling to make such a sound so i wonder whether it is even a possible articulation.

Comment: It's pretty much a "raspberry."

Comment: thanks. i think in that case we'll want to call it a lamino-labial trill (or linguolabial, as the answer below has), since it's the tongue blade rather than the apex against which the upper lip vibrates. right?

Comment: I'd have to say 'yes.'  However, it is possible to force air between to tip of a flattened tongue and the upper lip to make a trill.

Comment: just to be sure exactly where the air flows... http://milkandcookies.com/link/54954 (and because it's even funnier than the subject) :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds made using the tongue and lip/s are usually called "linguolabials" (eg in the IPA). There are a very few languages which make use of this sound as a phoneme, some examples are listed in the [Wikipedia article on linguolabials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguolabial_consonant). The article lists Coatlán Zapotec as having a linguolabial trill, but it appears to be iconic, used to represent a child's fart, not an actual phoneme.

There appear to be no reports of languages that use a linguolabial trill as a phoneme. [Edward Vajda](http://pandora.cii.wwu.edu/vajda/ling201/test2materials/Phonology3.htm) claims that the Chadic language Margi (spoken in Nigeria) has an "apico-labial flap", but this is not in agreement with other analyses of Margi (it may be that he meant to refer to the well-known labiodental flap of Margi).